# Sending parameters with a @POST request in java client

Tags: java, rest, maven, parameters, glassfish

I'm connecting to a SQL db via JDBC in a maven web app. I've created a restfull API.

I also have a java client which connects to my URI entry points and returns the output

i can successfully return data through the client if the uri has no params e.g.  .../users/getAll

I'm having some trouble with passing params to my post method on the server.

Server code

```
@POST
@Path("/NewUser")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<String> CreateUser(@HeaderParam("Name")String   name,@HeaderParam("Email")String email)
{
    if(name.equals("")||email.equals(""))
          return null;
    else return BankingService.CreateUser(name, email);
}
```

Client code

```
     WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

        String input = "{\"name\":tom,\"email\":\"tom@email.com\"}";

        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
                .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println(output);
```

I may be going about passing the parameters incorrectly,with the string input?
As the data is not being populated into the DB/
 any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below format.

```
String input = "{\"name\":\"tom\",\"email\":\"tom@email.com\"}";

ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
       .post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```